# how to convert datarow into datatable

Tags: asp.net

DataRow[] row = table.Select("Weight='57'");//  has  1  record
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();

```
     foreach (DataRow dr in row)
                {
                    dt.ImportRow(dr);
                }
                dt.AcceptChanges();
```

my  row has  1  record. when i  try to convert datarow[] row into datatable 
it  runs fine.  when   i check my  **table**  **dt**   it  does not contain  any record  in  it
. what is the issue in it

thank you

Answer (score 6):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("Your string");

DataTable dt1 = dr.copyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should copy the row into a new row, and than add it to the new table.
you can't take a row from one table and put it on another table.

Code Sample from another site:

```
DataTable dtDest = new DataTable();
dtDest = dsActivity.Tables[0].Clone();
foreach(DataRow dr in dsSrc.Tables[0].Rows)
{
 DataRow newRow = dtDest .NewRow();
 newRow.ItemArray = dr.ItemArray;
 dtDest.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

the clone makes the dtDest the same type (columns) as the source.

The other way is to create a new row, add the right columns, and copy value by value.

Answer (score 2):

```
DataRow[] rows = table.Select("Weight='57'");
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

foreach (DataRow item in rows)
{
    // add values into the datatable
    dt.Rows.Add(item.ItemArray);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
dt.Rows.Add(dr)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DataTable DT = DTMain.Clone();
// suppose DT is the table where we need to put datarows and DTMain is a table
// having the stucture of the datatbale, means you must have some structure for
// datatable.

//supposes you have a collection of datarows as

foreach(DataRow dr in DatarRowColl)
{
    DT.ImportRow(dr);
}

DT.AcceptChanges();

// here you get the datarows in a datatable.
```

Happy Programming.

Answer (score 1):

```
dim dt as new DataTable
dim row as new DataRow
dim params(10) as string
''''' imagine we have row and we fill it
''''' you should create your dataTable as you want
dt.Columns.Add("column1")
dt.Columns.Add("column2")
.
.
.
For Each r As DataRow In row
    params = {dr.Item("column1"), dr.Item("column2")}
    dt.Rows.Add(params)
Next
dt.AcceptChanges()
```